# Trying to configure parent link and child links in menu

Tags: 8

I'm trying to create a submenu in the same way shown in the screenshot[image: Configuration(parent) and Store, Products, Payment, Orders as the child links]

module.links.menu.yml:

```
custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export:
  title: 'Export'
  description: 'Export Menu'
  route_name: custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export
  parent: commerce.admin_commerce

custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export_sales_form:
  title: 'Export Sales'
  description: 'Export Sales to a CSV file.'
  route_name: custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export_sales_form
  parent: commerce.admin_commerce

custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export_menu_form:
  title: 'Export Menu'
  description: 'Export Menu to a CSV file.'
  route_name: custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export_menu_form
  parent: custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export
```

module.routing.yml

```
custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export:
  path: '/admin/commerce/export'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage'
    _title: 'Commerce'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access commerce administration pages'

custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export_sales_form:
  path: '/admin/commerce/export/sales'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Sales'
    _form: \Drupal\custom_forms_entity_export_csv\Form\SalesExportCsvForm
  requirements:
    _permission: 'use custom export csv'

custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export_menu_form:
  path: '/admin/commerce/export/menu'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Menu'
    _form: \Drupal\custom_forms_entity_export_csv\Form\MenuExportCsvForm
  requirements:
    _permission: 'use custom export csv'
```

module.links.task.yml

```
custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export_sales_form:
  title: 'Download Sales'
  base_route: custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export
  route_name: custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export_sales_form
  weight: 100

custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export_menu_form:
  title: 'Download Menu'
  base_route: custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export
  route_name: custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export_menu_form
  weight: 100
```

But all I end up with is all three links, Export, Export Sales, and Export Menu as children under the same Commerce menu, like shown here:
[image: All three export links are at the same level]

What I want is for Export to have an arrow on the right to expand a submenu containing Export Sales and Export Menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2nd menu link needs the `parent` property referencing your first `custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export` route :

```
custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export_sales_form:
  title: 'Export Sales'
  description: 'Export Sales to a CSV file.'
  route_name: custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export_sales_form
  parent: custom_forms_entity_export_csv.export
```

[image: Corrected custom commerce menu links]

Comment: I figured it out.  I had configured and moved the export menu and export sales links in the structure->menu settings and forgot.  Sometimes this mixture of configuration and code that have the same responsibilities drives me crazy.